# mysql query for join two table with like

Tags: php, mysql

```
company_name | macid          |  expiry_date
---------------------------------------------
abc          |  123456789012  |  2017-03-23
qwe          |  987654321012  |  2018-05-24
asd          |  456789123012  |  2019-07-07
abc          |  789456123000  |  2017-03-23
abc          |  445544444444  |  2018-03-03
abc          |  555555555555  |  2017-03-25


company_name | desktop         | server 
abc            123456789012      555555555555
               789456123000
```

I have above two table and I want all macid and expiry date which is present in table1 and table2. Also I have store all macid as new line and desktop macid and server macid in different columns. My query

```
"select a.macid,a.expity_date from table1 a,table2 b where a.macid like b.desktop or a.macid like %'b.server%'"
```

but is show result null. Please help to solved.

I want result

```
 macid          |  expiry_date
---------------------------------------------
 123456789012  |  2017-03-23
 789456123000  |  2017-03-23 
 555555555555  |  2017-03-25
```

for table2 if I want to search mac_id them I have to use

```
"select * from table2 where desktop like '%123456789012%'"
```

I can not retrieve record without %(percentage)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just a typo, not `expity_date`, it's `expiry_date` in your query, see [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/828e7/2).

```
select a.macid, a.expiry_date
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.macid like b.desktop or a.macid like b.server
```

However, it is more better to use `join` not a comma(,) to do join things:

```
select a.macid, a.expiry_date
from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.macid like b.desktop or a.macid like b.server
```

also check [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/828e7/3) here.
 Another thing is if `desktop` and `server` is as same as `macid`, just use equal(=) is fine as well.

Comment: I have mention that my all data are stored as new line. So I have to use like query with %%

Comment: @LOKESH Well, then use `like`:)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make two separate `JOIN` and then `UINON` the results.

```
SELECT macid, expiry_date
FROM table1 JOIN table2
ON table1.macid = table2.desktop
UNION
SELECT macid, expiry_date
FROM table1 JOIN table2
ON table1.macid = table2.server
```

Here is the working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dccea43/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"select a.macid,a.expity_date from table1 a JOIN table2 b ON (a.macid like b.desktop OR a.macid like b.server)"
```